# Different profile pictures for Main and Meta sites?

Tags: support, bug, profile-picture

As far as I know, our gravatar or avatar on the main site is carried to the meta site too. But yesterday, I found out that a  user by the name [user26375](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/16115/user26375?tab=profile) on Hinduism Stack Exchange has different avatars for main and meta sites. This is the same case for this user's accounts on other sites as well(Hat tip- @Pandya).

[image: Gif showing user's different gravatar on main and meta]

But it is not possible to change our profile picture from settings of Meta profile. There is no "Edit profile" option under Personal information in our Meta profile. So, I suspect this is a bug.

Is this a bug or an existing feature?

Comment: Might be the result of an account merge gone wrong?

Comment: The image URLs are different, so it's a problem on SE's end, not Gravatar's.

Comment: I observed from his network profile that this issue is prevailing on other communities also.